# printing the results of a fibonacci series

Tags: java, fibonacci

I know that the coding for the Fibonacci series is:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1) return n;
    else return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way, using the aforementioned code, to print the previous results of the series, but neither using a void function (that acts only like a printer of the series) or calling the fibonacci funcion for each calculation

I do not want to do this

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
     System.out.prinntln(fib(i));
}
```

Intead I want to only call the function once, like this:

fib(4);

and that the printing is:

0,1,1,2,3

of course using recursion

Any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
package Practice;

public class Fabonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a,b,c;
        a=0;
        b=1;
        c=2;

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            c=a+b;
            System.out.println(a);
            a=b;
            b=c;        
        }
    }
}
```

This will output as:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

Comment: This will output as

Comment: 0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I didn't see you would like to keep the recursion.

Then how about this:

```
public class fib {

  static int fibonacci(int value, boolean printThis) {
    int result;
    if (value==0 || value==1) {
      result = value;
      if (printThis) {
        System.out.print(result);
        System.out.print(", ");
      }
    } else {
      if (printThis) {
        result =  fibonacci(value-1, true)+fibonacci(value-2, false);
        System.out.print(result);
        System.out.print(", ");
      } else {
        result = fibonacci(value-1, false)+fibonacci(value-2, false);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    fibonacci(7, true);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

I don't see that you can do without the boolean `printThis` to control that only one path of the tree spawned by the recursion over two values is printed. To make this a little clearer, see how you could do this for faculty recursively.

The recursion calls the computation backwards, so `faculty(n)` is called before of `faculty(n-1)`. As you want print the value of `faculty(n-1)` before `faculty(n)`, you need to print before you return the value, like this:

```
static int faculty(int v) {
  int result;
  if (v==0) {
    result = 1;
  } else {
    result = v*faculty(v-1);
  }
  System.out.print(result);
  System.out.print(", ");
  return result;
}
```

This will give you the values in ascending order. I hope you can forgive the last comma, you will need to define an additional function if you want to get rid of this without a boolean parameter controlling this.

So you see you can do for faculty without the boolean to control the printing.

But that is due to the fact that `faculty` will not span a tree of recursive calls, but is just a single sequence of calls. As said before, I only see that you can control the printing if you have a whole tree of calls by adding a boolean functions.

Is that what you were after?

Anyway, here's still my first answer (which is more efficient, and will give you the same output faster):

Compute the Fibonacci numbers iteratively instead of recursively.

The easiest way is to use an array fib[].
Initialize with fib[0] = 0, fib[1] = 1.
Then iterate over i = 2 to n, where fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib [i-2].

It's also easy to tune this so you don't need the full array, but only two variables to store
fib[i-1], fib[i-2].

And in fact, you could take this iterative loop and then again make it a recursive loop, but it would have a different structure than your original fibonacci function.

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned in my post I really want to use it with recursion

Comment: @MrM.: ok, so I try to do this recursively. See my edits above.

Comment: @MrM: Have you tried my code? Works on my machine 8^) Is this the answer you were looking for, or what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Writing Fibonacci series in one line .

```
   public class Fib {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int i=1,f=0,n=0; n<15; n++,System.out.println(i=(f+(f+i))-(f=f+i)));            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that prints each calculation:

```
int x = 1;
int a = 0;
int t;

while(true)
{
    System.out.println(x);

    t = x;
    x = x + a;
    a = t;

    if (x > 30)
    {
        break;
    }        
}
```

This will print the following:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
```

This is the list of Fibonacci numbers less than 30.

Comment: thanks Michael for editing my text but in java its ok having or not spaces between variables

Answer (score 0):

You could write another method `void printFib(int n)` and then use the loop to print each `fib(n)` within this method. A method that returns a value really shouldn't be printing anything. But if you compute each number iteratively as Zane said, you can have a void method that computes and prints the values. I don't see any way to print the values within the recursive Fibonacci method.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example on Fibonnaci series.

```
class Fibonacci {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    fibonacciSeries(6);

}

static void fibonacciSeries(int num) {
    int a = 0, b = 1, i, c;

    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            c = i;
        } else {
            c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        System.out.print(c);
        if(i != num) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

0,1,1,2,3,5,8

Answer (score 0):

**I hope its easy way to print Fibonacci Series**

> Fibonacci Series

```
public class Fib
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int first=0,second=1;next;
System.out.prinf("%d %d ",first,second);
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
     next=first+second;
     first=second;
     second=next;
     System.out.printf("%d ",second);
       }
   }
}
```

> Output

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain how your answer is different or better than those already posted.

Comment: I used next,first and second as a variable in the program.Its very easy to understand how the program works and specially for new programmer. That's why i think this code is different from others.

Answer (score 0):

This could be nice one...

```
 public static void febonassi(int range, int pre, int nxt) {
    System.out.println(pre);
    if (nxt <= range)
        febonassi(range, nxt, nxt + pre);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used int array of size `howManyDigit`.

This is the best way i can write *Fibonacci series* using less variables

```
    int[] array = new int[howManyDigit];
    for(int i=0;i<howManyDigit;i++){
        if(i>1)
             array [i]=array [i-1]+array [i-2];
        else
            array [i]=i;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.

Comment: You have to do that in answer section by clicking on edit , visibility of comments is limited as some comments gets hidden when no. of comments grow.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is the most efficient and fastest way I could came out for the Fibonacci Sequence:

**FIBONACCI DYNAMIC VERSION**

```
public static BigInteger getFibonacciDynamic(long n) {

    BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[(int) n + (n == 0 ? 2 : 1)];
    fibonacci[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    fibonacci[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1].add(fibonacci[i - 2]);
    }

    return fibonacci[(int) n];
}
```

You could run it this way for the first 1000 values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int index = 0;
    while (index < 1000) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BigInteger value = getFibonacciDynamic(index);
        System.out.println("VALUE: " + value + " TOOK: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms" + " OF INDEX: " + index);
        index++;
    }
}
```

And will print out:

```
VALUE: 0 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 0
VALUE: 1 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 1
VALUE: 1 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 2
VALUE: 2 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 3
VALUE: 3 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 4
VALUE: 5 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 5
VALUE: 8 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 6
VALUE: 13 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 7
VALUE: 21 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 8
VALUE: 34 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 9
VALUE: 55 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 10
VALUE: 89 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 11
VALUE: 144 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 12
VALUE: 233 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 13
VALUE: 377 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 14
VALUE: 610 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 15
VALUE: 987 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 16
VALUE: 1597 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 17
VALUE: 2584 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 18
VALUE: 4181 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 19
VALUE: 6765 TOOK: 0ms OF INDEX: 20
... till index 1000 with always < 10ms for each value
```

If you use recursive at index 45 is going to take this long:

**FIBONACCI RECURSIVE**

```
public static long getFibonacci(long n) {
    if(n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return getFibonacci(n - 1) + getFibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}

---- PRINT ----
VALUE: 1134903170 TOOK: 9991ms OF INDEX: 45
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT1]**  https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/2N3 
I fixed my function for print N_0, it's cool:

```
public class Main
{
    public static int f(int n, boolean p, int level, final int deep) {
        if (n < 2) {
            if (p || level == deep) System.out.println(1);
            return 1;
        } else {
            int res = f(n-1, true && p, level + 1, deep) + f(n-2, false, level + 1, deep);
            if (p) {
                System.out.println(res);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        f(n, true, 0, n-1); // print recursive
    }
}
```

I can do it in one func, but lost number N_0, like this:
https://onlinegdb.com/S1M0SuEPv

I explain it like stack of recursive function when it be called:
[image]

> So the value of return function will like this stack:

[image]

> We need to print the number in circle, so I include a boolean param
> for do it:

```
public class Main
{
    public static int f(int n, boolean p) {
        if (n < 2) {
            if (p) System.out.println(1);
            return 1;
        } else {
            int res = f(n-1, true && p) + f(n-2, false);
            if (p) {
                System.out.println(res);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1);
        f(10, true); // print recursive
    }
}
```

The result is very beautiful :))

> 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 1;
int n1 = 0 , n2 = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(i < 1)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    else if(i > 1)
    {
        System.out.print(sum);
        System.out.print(" ");
        sum = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that future readers could understand it easily.